# Can not write in a cell in Libre Office Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I can not write anything in the circled cell.
I created the document in Libre Office, and I can write in any other row or cell beside this one. 
I tried to enlarge it but nothing.
The mouse cursor just won't stay in it.
What can I do?

[image: screen shot]

[image]

Comment: Can you show more, like the top ruler and the total cell?  Also, display all non-printing characters, like formatting markers.  Is that an actual table cell or just a margin between columns?  Can you enter text in the cell above it?

Comment: The rulers are in fact very important in that case. Look at the cell at the right: The indentation of the paragraph's first line seems to be quite big, at least bigger than the marked cell's width. I assume the marked cell's content has the same paragraph style, esp. first-line indentation as the cell right of it.

Comment: Sorry, I can not post the correct link. I will try again: https://i62.servimg.com/u/f62/12/38/23/87/screen12.png

Comment: I added the image, but the detail people need to see is pretty small.  Any chance of posting a full-sized image?

Comment: Can you describe how you created the table, and any columns you inserted later?  Some of the columns are not reflected with a bar on the top ruler, and the border to the left of the problem column has markings on the top ruler that are too small to make out.

Comment: I really do not what what was happening but after merging some cells, Libre Office started to crash several times... I tried and copy cell by cell (only by selectinb the text) to a new document (thinking that maybe the table was used from an MS Word document). But while I was copying the data cell by cell, the crashes started again. I noticed that there is an update to the suite and I installed it. Right now I am working in the new document, ODT format, and everything is OK. Every cell. I think the problem is solved, but I will come back in a few hours to tell you if everything is really OK.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is not reproducible, and the question was revised and posted as https://superuser.com/q/1315717/364367